# Change property depending on property in other control - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I want to use some kind of trigger to change a button in my window to `IsEnabled = False` when the textbox property `Validation.HasErrors` of my textbox is `True`.

Can I do this with Triggers of some kind on the Button?

If yes, some example would be nice!

Comment: The WPF TextBox object doesn't have a Validation property - am I missing something?

Comment: Jake: you're missing the Validation.HasError attached property.

Comment: @itowlson: thanks, posting this in case i'm not the only person who still has things to learn about wpf ;)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a Style.  If you want to tie it directly to the text box, you could do something like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="DisabledOnErrors" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasErrors)}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

---

```
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DisabledOnErrors}" 
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox}" />
```

This works if the button is not already binding to the DataContext for other properties.  In this case, the Style is reusable for other button and text box pairings.

Comment: Is it possible to apply to multiple textboxes for one button?

Comment: You could try using a MultiBinding and a custom IMultiValueConverter.  I don't have much experience with these, but the general idea would be to bind the button IsEnabled directly to a MultiBinding that binds to all of the text box (Validation.HasErrors), using the ElementName syntax itowlson showed below.  You would then need an IMultiValueConverter that would take a list of bool values and then take the NOT of ORing them all together.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with triggers, but because you are referring to another element, you must use a DataTrigger rather than a normal Trigger:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasError), ElementName=tb}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Note you must use a Style rather than the Button.Triggers collection, because Button.Triggers can contain only EventTriggers.

Comment: I'm trying this with an Image and the Visibility property and it doesn't work. When I use a Button (with the Visibility property) it does work. I just cannot figure out why. Any thoughts? Thanx, Marc.